# Filtrar una lista por una propiedad que es una lista con items de otra lista con Linq

Tags: c#, linq

tengo una lista de objetos (Facturas) que tienen una propiedad que a su vez también es una lista (DetalleFactura) de objetos de tipo LineaFactura.
Por otro lado tengo una lista de strings que representa los items por los que filtrar.
Sería algo así:

```
 public class LineaFactura
   {
      public int NumLinea { get; set; }
      public int Cantidad { get; set; }
      public string Producto { get; set; }
      public int Precio { get; set; }
   }

   public class Factura
   {
      public int NumFactura { get; set; }
      public List<LineaFactura> DetalleFactura { get; set; }
   }

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         List<Factura> facturas = new List<Factura>();
         Factura factura = null;
         List <LineaFactura> lineasFactura = null;
         LineaFactura lineafactura = null;

         factura = new Factura();
         factura.NumFactura = 1;
         lineasFactura = new List<LineaFactura>();
         lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 1, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod1", Precio = 2 };
         lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
         lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 2, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod2", Precio = 3 };
         lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
         facturas.Add(factura);

         factura = new Factura();
         factura.NumFactura = 2;
         lineasFactura = new List<LineaFactura>();
         lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 1, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod3", Precio = 5 };
         lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
         facturas.Add(factura);

         factura = new Factura();
         factura.NumFactura = 3;
         lineasFactura = new List<LineaFactura>();
         lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 1, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod1", Precio = 2 };
         lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
         lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 2, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod3", Precio = 3 };
         lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
         facturas.Add(factura);

         List<string> listaProductos = new List<string>() { "Prod1", "Prod3" };

         //Aquí filtro las facturas por la lista de productos
         var listaFacturas = facturas.??????

         //En listaFacturas debería tener:
         /*
          * Factura 1 Linea 1
          * Factura 3 Linea 1
          * Factura 3 Linea 3
          */

      }
   }
```

Lo que necesito es obtener las facturas y sus lineas que tengan el producto en la lista que hace de filtro mediante una única instrucción de Linq si es posible.
En el ejemplo, tal y como indico en los comentarios, deberían quedar solamente:

Factura 1 Linea 1
Factura 3 Linea 1
Factura 3 Linea 3

Gracias.

Comment: De la factura 2 también te debería dar la linea 1 no?

Comment: Tienes razón Marc, aunque la verdad es que se me ha ido a mi :)   En la factura dos quería poner Prod2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando el método `SelectMany`.

En tu código también te falta asociar las líneas de factura a la propiedad `DetalleFactura`:

```
List<Factura> facturas = new List<Factura>();
Factura factura = null;
List<LineaFactura> lineasFactura = null;
LineaFactura lineafactura = null;

factura = new Factura();
factura.NumFactura = 1;
lineasFactura = new List<LineaFactura>();
lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 1, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod1", Precio = 2 };
lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 2, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod2", Precio = 3 };
lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
factura.DetalleFactura = lineasFactura;
facturas.Add(factura);

factura = new Factura();
factura.NumFactura = 2;
lineasFactura = new List<LineaFactura>();
lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 1, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod3", Precio = 5 };
lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
factura.DetalleFactura = lineasFactura;
facturas.Add(factura);

factura = new Factura();
factura.NumFactura = 3;
lineasFactura = new List<LineaFactura>();
lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 1, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod1", Precio = 2 };
lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
lineafactura = new LineaFactura() { NumLinea = 2, Cantidad = 1, Producto = "Prod3", Precio = 3 };
lineasFactura.Add(lineafactura);
factura.DetalleFactura = lineasFactura;
facturas.Add(factura);

List<string> listaProductos = new List<string>() { "Prod1", "Prod3" };

// Si lo que quires es obtener las líneas de factura que tengan alguno de los productos
Console.WriteLine("Líneas");
var lineas = facturas.SelectMany(
        f => f.DetalleFactura.Select(l => new {f.NumFactura, l.NumLinea, l.Producto}))
    .Where(l => listaProductos.Contains(l.Producto));
foreach (var linea in lineas)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Factura {linea.NumFactura} Línea {linea.NumLinea} {linea.Producto}");
}

Console.WriteLine("\nFacturas");
// Para sacar una lista de facturas únicamente con las líneas del filtro
var facturasFiltradas = facturas.Where(f => f.DetalleFactura.Any(l => listaProductos.Contains(l.Producto)))
    .Select(
        f =>
            new Factura()
            {
                NumFactura = f.NumFactura,
                DetalleFactura = f.DetalleFactura.Where(l => listaProductos.Contains(l.Producto)).ToList()
            });
foreach (var facturaFiltrada in facturasFiltradas)
{
    foreach (var lineaFactura in facturaFiltrada.DetalleFactura)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Factura {facturaFiltrada.NumFactura} Línea {lineaFactura.NumLinea} {lineaFactura.Producto}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Asier, tu código funciona perfecto. Pero si lo que necesito es obtener una lista de objetos Factura, ¿cómo lo hago?. (Seguramente no me expliqué bien en la pregunta) Gracias

Comment: ¿Pero objetos factura con todas las líneas o únicamente con las líneas que contienen esos productos?

Comment: Únicamente con las líneas que contienen los productos del filtro.

Comment: He editado el ejemplo para contemplar este segundo caso

Comment: Gracias Asier, funciona perfecto, era justamente eso. Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda e interés. Un saludo.